# Can a whole cause be a humanity tether for a kindred?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

I'm admittedly not sure if I've phrased this properly or not, but - you obviously get touchstones, where individual humans help serve as tethers to humanity for a kindred. Mechanically so too.

But I was also wondering - some Kindred (some Brujah especially) have been shown in canon to continue to have investments in human causes such as in relation to civil rights - to the extent that they're heavily involved in these causes and continue to help work for them and along with humans also working for them accordingly.

**As such: can *whole causes* help tether a kindred to their humanity much like a touchstone does?
Or do only specific actions/individual touchstones do that?**

Answer (score 4):

### Not yet...but it's expected.

The rules in the Vampire 5E corebook presume that your touchstone is a mortal, but alternate paths of morality will be available in **Cults of the Blood Gods**, and among them are [expected](https://twitter.com/clackclickbang/status/1101884730595856385?lang=en) rules for using other things as touchstones.